# Please explain some of the features of URL Rewrite module for a newbie

Tags: server, iis, iis7, url-rewriting

I am learning to use the IIS Rewrite module and some of the "features" listed in the page is confusing me. It would be great if somebody could explain them to me and give a first hand account of when you would use the feature.

Thanks a lot!

> Rewriting within the content of
>   specific HTML tags

```
Access to server variables and HTTP headers
Rewriting of server variables and HTTP request headers
```

What are the "server variables" and when would you redefine or define them?

```
Rewriting of HTTP response headers
```

> HtmlEncode function

Why would you use an HTMLEncode in the server?

> Reverse proxy rule template
>
> Support for IIS kernel-mode and
>   user-mode output caching
>
> Failed Request Tracing support

Answer (score 1):

Server Variables are variables that IIS sets and provides to your application and are relative to the HTTP request and response.  They are an accumlation of information based on HTTP headers, IP connections, authentication, authorization, etc.

An example of using a rewrite rule with Server Variables could be to provide the original URL of your resource prior to the the URL rewrite.  Your target application could then use the original URL in some piece of logic such as tracking uses of the original URL.

HTMLEncode will take special characters that are part of the HTML markup syntax and encode them to be output as HTML.  This makes it easier to send output from the server side in that you don't have to manually create the markup as you're sending it.